# ArcGIS Field Calculator Python numbering rows of fishnet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a grid of 100*100 cells. I want to add to each cell a number representing the row it is in (like in excel). I added a field and want try to solve that with field calculator:

The code is something like this:

```
def test( OBJECTID ):

 if OBJECTID > 0 and OBJECTID < 101:
     return 1

 elif OBJECTID > 100 and OBJECTID < 201:
     return 2

 elif OBJECTID > 200 and OBJECTID < 301:
     return 3

 elif OBJECTID > 300 and OBJECTID < 401:
     return 4

 elif OBJECTID > 400 and OBJECTID < 501:
     return 5

 elif  OBJECTID > 500 and OBJECTID < 601:
     return 6

 elif  OBJECTID > 600 and OBJECTID < 701:
     return 7
```

This works good, however I want to automate it a little bit. The return value shall automatically be counted to the next number.

I tried to solve this with autoincrement. Though it adds a number per cell and not per row. Any ideas how to solve that?

Meanwhile I figured, that the cells of each row have obviously the same coordinates and with the help of another guy I have now this code. However I receive only NULL values for the fields. Any ideas what is wrong

```
def test( X_KORD_ED ):
    var = 0
    old_i = object() 

    for i in X_KORD_ED: 
        if i != old_i:
            var += 1
            old_i = i
        yield i, var
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I solved the problem via the coordiantes of the cells/polygons. I summarized the x and y coordinate, exported it to excel, added 1-100 and ABC and joined it back to the feature class.

Answer (score 3):

Calculate based on the shape Xmin minus the feature class Xmin (the origin), the divide by the cell width.

So The function will be something like:

```py
get_rownum(!shape.extent.XMin!, !shape.extent.XMax!)
```

And the code block will be something like:

```py
def get_rownum(xmin, xmax):
    return (xmin - origin) // (xmax - xmin) #fill in the origin
```

For help see some [examples of using field calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002m000000).

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the row number and the column number.

When you reach the end of the row (column number =100) then increment the row number and start the column number at 1.

Keep going until you have completed the last row.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the example code. could you please give a hint what to change exactley on the code?

Comment: Simpler: the row is one greater than the integer part of `OBJECTID/100`.