# Labeling Grid Index Features according to location in another Grid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, data-driven-pages

I am trying to create a product using Arc in which one Grid Index is subdivided into a smaller Grid Index.  Creating the two grids is no problem, however the automatic naming convention is not ideal for the subdivisions.  I would like to come up with a method of quickly naming the smaller grid squares according to where they are located within the larger grid, without having to manually label each grid square.  For example, Grid A1 would contain 4 smaller squares, labeled 1,2,3,4.  For scalability, I am really trying to create a workflow for this process that is not horrible.

[image: The larger of the two grid index layers:]

[image: Default labeling]

Comment: Yes. It will require a custom script. You may want to  look into this question - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90863/add-row-and-column-name-to-square-grid-feature-in-arcgis